# How to run Python code made for Android device on Windows 10?

Tags: python, android, kivy

I am making an `Android` app with `Python` (`kivy`), and I am using `plyer`'s `stt`, which only supports Android. I used `Pydroid3` to check my code, and it works, but I don't want to send the code from my pc to my phone every time I want to check if it works. Is there any way to run a .py file that only works on Android, on a Windows device? Like a virtual phone or something?

Comment: I know that windows 11 has implemented the Subsystem for Android, but I don't know if you can do what you are asking with it.  You could check [Windows Subsystem for Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/android/wsa/) to see if it would be suitable for you situation.

Comment: Yeah I have already read that. I should have clarified that I am i using Windows 10, my bad. I edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio) has a built in [Android Device Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator?gclid=CjwKCAjw-8qVBhANEiwAfjXLrhdso_vCxb9Vl8Iwcddo_aFRBYWvBxNRigAq7UzwJSEAWpaB9RFsYBoCtGcQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds), wich is basically a virtual Android device. Inside that you can download `Pydroid 3` and run your Python code there. If your application requires addiditional permissions, you can use `Pydroid Additional Permissions Plugin`.